# Does a solution exist for $y'=(y^2-1)e^{2012y-1}, y(0)=1$ such that $\lim_{t \to \infty} y(t)=-1$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does a solution exist for $y'=(y^2-1)e^{2012y-1}, y(0)=1$ such that $\lim_{t \to \infty} y(t)=-1$? The solution key states that such solution does exist due to Picard's uniqueness theorem. I can show that $y(t)=1$ is a solution and that a solution satisfies either $y(\infty)=1$ or $y(\infty)=-1$. But why existence of a solution with $-1$ as asymptotic value? I don't see how Picard's uniqueness theorem comes into play.

Comment: If $y(0)=1$ what is $y'(0)$?

Comment: Picard's uniqueness theorem says nothing of the sort, and the answer is clearly wrong, given this information.

Comment: @Paul The source is indeed dubious but can you give your reasoning why it does not exist? I can see $y'(0)=0$ but that does not imply $y$ is constant, does it?

Answer (score 1):

You have found $y=1$ as solution, and by the uniqueness theorem it is the only solution with $y(0)=1$. This already fixes the asymptotic behavior.